# Can I use PreactJS with React Native using preact-compat (Or using any other method)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, preact

I've been working with react and react native for a while and there's a library that caught my attention: Preact. I learned it (that being a react developer was not difficult), I did some PWA's to practice (Copying medium-sized projects that I've done in the past) and, if you know what Preact is, it goes without saying my impression. It seems incredible to me. My question is: is there a way to work with react native using Preact? Maybe with preact-compat?

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box, no. [See this discussion from GitHub](https://github.com/preactjs/preact/discussions/3035)

> The short answer is: use a native wrapper that exposes DOM.
>
> The long answer is that there are woefully few options for this. Some time ago, I had begun building a DOM interface to React Native, but I have no experience with React Native whatsoever and I'm likely not the best person to do that implementation.
>
> I do know that folks have used Preact with NativeScript and had some success: NativeScript doesn't expose a Web-compatible DOM, but its UI primitives are still quite easily mapped to DOM primitives:
>
> - https://github.com/staydecent/nativescript-preact
> - https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-dom/blob/master/src/dom.js
>
> It would also be relatively easy to implement a nativescript-preact using the source of nativescript-vue, which implements a simple DOM on top of NativeScript's UI components that Vue then renders to:
> https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/tree/master/platform/nativescript

It's also worth noting that `preact-compat` is the legacy package, used for Preact 8.x and prior. `preact/compat` is where you'd get compat going forward.